# Loop/cbind on column names (character)

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, character

I am currently working on a database made of 60 time series. I actually have two data sets: each one corresponds to a specific variable ( A or B).
Please find an example below (even though my real database contains 60 names and 51 years)
Variable A

```
year name1 name2 name3 
2002   39   56   31 
2003   37   31   52 
2004   51   58   51 
2005   70   59   68 
2006   41   43   37 
2007   43   31   53
```

Variable B:

```
year name1 name2 name3 
2002   56   18   24 
2003   72   52   59 
2004   32   30   33 
2005   33   34   51 
2006   47   46   19 
2007   19   32   25
```

I would like to implement a loop that would create the following matrix for each name.

ie: for name1

```
year var1 var2 
2002   39   56 
2003   37   72 
2004   51   32 
2005   70   33 
2006   41   47 
2007   43   19
```

At first, I did the following (because I am only interested in the series that come up in both datasets)

```
names=as.matrix(intersect(colnames(df.var_A),colnames(df.var_B))) 
DF.VAR_A=subset(df.var_A,select=noms) 
DF.VAR_B=subset(df.var_B,select=noms)
```

Then I would like to get the series (A and B) corresponding to each name

I get the years :

```
YEAR=DF.VAR_A[,"year"]
```

As expected I find:

```
 DF.VAR_A[,"name1"] 
[1] 39 37 51 70 41 43
```

Now I would like to create a dataframe for each name, made of the year, values corresponding to variable A and values corresponding to variable B.

I take off "YEAR" from the name vector.

```
NAMES=names[-c(1)]
```

Then I have tried :

```
DATA=NULL 
for (i in 1:length(NAMES)){ 
DATA[i]=cbind(YEAR,DF.VAR_A[,i],DF.VAR_B[,i]) 
}
```

But the following warning comes uo:
1: In DATA[i] = cbind(Année, DF.VAR_A[, i], DF.VAR_B[, i]) : 
le nombre d'objets à remplacer n'est pas multiple de la taille du remplacement

To sum up, I would like to get the 3 different dataframes (1 for each name), to then be able to apply a loop ( that I have already programmed). I want to "automate" the loop to every serie.
I hope it's clear...

Any idea?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Since you are quite new here, you might want to read the [**about**](http://stackoverflow.com/about) and [**FAQ**](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) sections of the website to help you get the most out of it. If an answer does solve your problem you may want to *consider* upvoting and/or marking it as accepted to show the question has been answered, by ticking the little green check mark next to the suitable answer. You are **not** obliged to do this, but it helps keep the site clean of unanswered questions and rewards those who take the time to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to me you are just `cbind`ing things together. This will do it very simply and each subset will be its own list element (but there are plenty of other ways to do it if you need something more programatically robust):

```
lapply( 2:ncol(varA) , function(x) cbind( Year = varA[,1] , A = varA[ , x], B = varB[,x] ) )
[[1]]
     Year  A  B
[1,] 2002 39 56
[2,] 2003 37 72
[3,] 2004 51 32
[4,] 2005 70 33
[5,] 2006 41 47
[6,] 2007 43 19

[[2]]
     Year  A  B
[1,] 2002 56 18
[2,] 2003 31 52
[3,] 2004 58 30
[4,] 2005 59 34
[5,] 2006 43 46
[6,] 2007 31 32

[[3]]
     Year  A  B
[1,] 2002 31 24
[2,] 2003 52 59
[3,] 2004 51 33
[4,] 2005 68 51
[5,] 2006 37 19
[6,] 2007 53 25
```